# How to setup DHCP relay in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dhcp

I am new in Linux, so please ignore if my question is silly.
I am setting up 4 machines. Two machines are the servers and two are client computers for testing purposes.
I am using my Ubuntu machine as a router to allow client machines to communicate with my windows server on the other subnet. My windows server has the ip 192.168.1.1 and Ubuntu connected to windows network 192.168.1.2. Clients will have DHCP.
I have installed dhcp on windows server 2008 and configured everything. I have also configured my Ubuntu machine to act as a DHCP relay, but the problem is that client don't receive any IP addresses

I was thinking that the problem might be windows server leasing addresses that are not part of its subnet. DHCP is leasing 10.0.0.0 addresses while it's own network is 192.168.1.0

I have disabled firewall on clients and servers, but still no!

Comment: You wrote you "set up dhcp (on the 2008 server) and configured all".
But then, why didn't you configure the proper dhcp range(s) for the linux subnet?
Or did I misunderstand
" windows server leasing addresses that are not part of its subnet. DHCP is leasing 10.0.0.0 addresses while it's own network is 192.168.1.0"? Or does the windows server subnet (then it must also work as a router with two interfaces/IPs?) run on 10.0.0.0 range?

Comment: DHCP server has ip address of 192.168.1.1, but it leases ip for 10.0.0.0 network which is on the other side of the Linux router. I am able to ping from DHCP server to both clients if I assign static ip addresses